# Complete and utter nonsense with Overlay and Graphics

Tags: graphics, text, overlay

I'm trying to simply overlay some text and a scalebar onto an image. I'm getting (what I perceive to be) completely ridiculous results while trying to do this.

Here's the code:

```
img = Import@"http://i.imgur.com/PVUXYz5.png"

Manipulate[
overlay = 
Graphics[{Text[Style["50 Magnets", White, 30], {250, 250}], {White,
   AbsoluteThickness[5], Line[{{i, 200}, {i + 50, 200}}]}}];, 
{i, 1, 450, 1}]

Dynamic@Overlay[{img, overlay}]
```

The only thing I'm `Manipulate`ing, as far as I can see, is the x-values of the points where I'd like my `Line` to show up. When I increase `i`, I expect the `Line` just to move from left to right. Instead, the line shrinks and grows in size and *translates* around.

[image: nonsense graphics]

Not only *that*, but the `Text` moves around, too! I cannot for the life of me see why this is happening. I expect that I have a misunderstanding of how `Graphics` is working, but even breaking it up into two `Graphics` objects and combining them with `Show` results in the exact same behavior.

Does anybody know why this happens and what I could do to fix it? Ostensibly, adding two words and a line to an image (and mapping this operation to a list of images once I figure this out) shouldn't be difficult, but this may be the oddest behavior I've ever seen from *Mathematica* and I'm just totally clueless.

Comment: use the option `PlotRange` in `Graphcis`;, e.g.,  `PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 500}}`?

Comment: You know, that's a great idea. I know that Plots, et c. are Graphics objects, but never thought about how that implied that I could use PlotRange on other Graphics objects. 

I think that that does, in fact, work, but now while the Line shows up in the right place, the image is (as it was before) improperly scaled and so the line/text don't show up where they ought to. `ImageDimensions` returns 500x500, but that's not how it's rendering. Even forcing `ImageSize` doesn't change it.

Comment: Your graphic makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to @kglr comment. I would recommend placing all in a single `Manipulate` and making use of `Prolog` for the `img` background.  The Graphic is actually resetting its `PlotRange` as it is redrawn.  This is why you need to set it as constant.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style["50 Magnets", White, 30], {250, 250}],
   {White, AbsoluteThickness[5], Line[{{i, 200}, {i + 50, 200}}]}},
  PlotRange -> Transpose@{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions@img},
  Prolog -> {Inset[img, Center, Center, ImageDimensions@img]}],
 {i, 1, 450, 1}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely helps a ton; I think that'll let me get to where I need to be. Thanks a ton, and thanks to @kglr for pointing out the `PlotRange` thing!

Comment: One thing I don't understand (cf. the comment on my original post) is why the sizes are so messed up. Everything now scales properly, but the result of this `Manipulate` command is a 540x540 image—I dunno from where it gets that number. When I set the `ImageSize` in `Graphics` to `{500,500}`, it renders at 750x750. I wonder if this is because I have the default notebook magnification set to 1.5x due to my display's resolution... I figure it'll export properly though with a forced `ImageSize`, so no worries.